# How place logos at different positions in latex beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, logos

Hello everyone how to make a similar template in latex, the problem I am facing is putting different [logos at specified positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNuVY.png) on the title page.

Here are the pages.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.